# How to autocomplete per conditions in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When coding in vim, I add autocomplete for `"{('` in vimrc as below:

```
inoremap " ""<ESC>i
inoremap ' ''<ESC>i
inoremap { {<Cr>}<Esc>O
inoremap ( ()<ESC>i
```

But I find it's quite annoying to add an additional semicolon `;` manually in the end of a function call or expression.
Example 1: `print("hello world");` => autocomplete should be `);` when input `(`
Example 2: `if (true)` or `while (true)` => autocomplete should be only `)` when input `(`

When inputting a single `(`, how to autocomplete correctly for both example 1 and example 2? My focus here is whether there are some easy ways to add `if/else` for key mapping.

Comment: And what you're going to do with `foo = bar() + baz();` ?

Comment: If you *really* want this type of completion, then adopt a plug-in such as https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs which will have figured out the corner cases for you. No it won't add `;` automatically, but it lets you easily type `)` to jump to after the closing paren so you can add the `;` yourself. And some shortcuts to "jump" a few closing brackets. (Personally, I find this kind of auto-completion to be more trouble than it's worth it, but that's just my opinion...)

Comment: @Matt, you are right that my original idea could not cover the case you mentioned, maybe the question should be change to this: Is there any way to add some "if/else" style conditions for the autocomplete?

Comment: @filbranden As a new vim user, I have similar troubles as you when using plugins. That's why I would like to customize some daily commands by myself so that I can control it. I once installed a hands of plugins which finally crushed my vim environment. I would not touch plugins before I could understand vim well enough to solve those plugin conflicts.

Comment: That's not what I said. I don't have problems with plug-ins (though I acknowledge adding tons of plug-ins that you don't understand is definitely a bad idea.) What I said is that I generally dislike the feature of completing pairs while typing, because more often than not I find myself fighting the feature (having to remove brackets added by the feature that I didn't really want.) I find that you need to be quite disciplined to be able to effectively use such a feature.

Comment: If you *do* want this feature, I definitely recommend that you do so through the plug-in rather than roll your own. It's not a feature that is simple to get right and plug-in authors have put a lot of effort to make it work correctly in all (or most) corner cases. These plug-ins have also had many users test it and report bugs to improve quality. The plug-in is definitely the way to go!

Comment: If you add an auto-pairs plug-in (such as the one I mentioned, although there are others, you might want to look for them and compare a few), I definitely recommend you also get vim-surround (it's a good idea to get it regardless), which will give you Normal mode commands to surround a specific area. I find that's the biggest shortcoming of auto-pairs, when you want to surround text that's already there, it tends to insert the closing bracket when you insert the opening one, but in that case you actually only want one of them, so you end up going to fix the edits.

Comment: Using vim-surround effectively helps you avoid these mistakes. Regardless, if you end up adding these plug-ins (or any plug-ins), spend time learning to use the plug-ins. Read the README from the GitHub repository. Read the help, in full. Try the keybindings. Adding plug-ins and not taking the time to learn them is the problem... Rather than avoiding plug-ins altogether, address the problem of adding plug-ins you that don't know how they actually work or are supposed to be used.

Comment: @filbranden, thanks for the suggestion, after days of vim study and practice, I learned a lot, now I could use vim-surround pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a pretty challenging task to handle all the options properly. But if all you ask is just a simple and very incomplete example code then, perhaps, this small snippet could be of some help:

```
inoremap <expr>( Paren()

function! Paren() abort
    return printf("()%s\<Left>",
        \ search('\v(if|while)\s*%#', 'bn', line('.')) ? "" : ";\<Left>")
endfunction
```

The idea is to match the current line (just before the cursor) against regex. Depending on the result, we build an expression to be inserted.

See `:h search()`, `:h :map-expression` etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I spent many days to study vim to understand this solution, and it works well